# How to check if a media file is a video and not an image in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, kotlin

So I have this comparison window, where the app compares a sample image to a image that was either uploaded or taken by the phones camera. This comparison window also pops up when the user takes or uploads videos. But that's where the issue is. It is only meant to compare images and not videos. Every time I decline a video from matching a sample picture, the app crashes. So the solution would be having the comparison window only pop up when an image is being uploaded and have the videos uploaded without the comparison window.

So I think the code here controls when the comparison window pops up when the user uploads a video or an image

```
override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

        if (mediaLoadManager.isMediaEditRequestCode(requestCode)) {
            val newUri = mediaLoadManager.handleLoadMediaResult(
                requestCode, resultCode, data,
                requireContext().applicationContext
            ) { tmpMediaInfo ->
                if (tmpMediaInfo.errorMsg != null) {
                    processViewModel.updateMediaCount(null)
                    processViewModel.updateMediaListInfoAfterEditError(tmpMediaInfo.errorMsg)
                } else {
                    processViewModel.updateMediaListInfoAfterEdit(tmpMediaInfo)
                    progressDialogMediaCompress?.show()
                }

            }

            processViewModel.pictureDescriptionAndCompressionLiveData.observe(viewLifecycleOwner,
                EventObserver { pictureDescriptionAndCompression ->
                    // if condition is true, show "showDoesThePictureTakenResemblesTheSample"
                    if (pictureDescriptionAndCompression != PICTURE_DESCRIPTION_NOT_AVAILABLE) {
                        if (newUri != null && pictureDescriptionAndCompression == SiteSurveyTypeProgressViewModel.COMPRESSED) {
                            progressDialogMediaCompress?.dismiss()
                            processViewModel.updateMediaCount(newUri)
                            switchToUI(UiType.COMPARE_MEDIA_DIALOG_FRAGMENT, args = Bundle().apply {
                                putParcelable(KEY_MEDIA_URI, newUri)
                            }, parentFragmentManager)
                        }else if (pictureDescriptionAndCompression == SiteSurveyTypeProgressViewModel.NOT_COMPRESSED){
                            progressDialogMediaCompress?.dismiss()
                            showMediaSizeTooLargeAlert()
                        }
                    }
                })

        }
    }
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated, Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

A flimsy solution would be to use **mime types** and only accept ones related to images. But this leaves your program vulnerable to abuse as a simply diguised non image file with let's say png extension could make your app behave unpredictably.

I would suggest opening an input stream using the file uri, reading **a chunk of beginning data** of the file in binary and only accepting files that have headers specific to image files.

Popular file formats have *headers* which is basically some unique combination of binary code placed at the beginning of a file to identify the file as that specific format. BMP, PNG, JPEG, ICO, etc image files have different headers. All we have to do is read the header length amount of data from the file and see if it is consistent with any image file headers and this way we have a more reliable way of ensuring file formats.

On a relatively higher level, the data is represented and compared usually in hex format rather than binary.

Hope this helps.